# c# how can i end my GOTO statement and go on after

Tags: c#, element, goto, skip

I want to go somewhere in my code with the goto statement but it doesn't skip parts of my code but reads on.
I just need to skip the parts i don't need...
code:

```
   int getal1, getal2;
        int som,verschil,product,quotient;


        Console.WriteLine("first number: ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        getal1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("choose operator: -,+,*,/");
        if (Console.ReadLine() == "+")
        {
            goto second;
        }
        else if (Console.ReadLine() == "-")
        {
            goto second1;
        }

second:
            Console.WriteLine("Second number(+): ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            getal2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ResetColor();
            goto Operat;

Operat:     som = getal1 + getal2;
            verschil = getal1 - getal2;
            product = getal1 * getal2;
            quotient = getal1 / getal2;
             goto optelling;

second1:    Console.WriteLine("Second number(-): ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            getal2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ResetColor();
            goto Operat1;

Operat1:
            som = getal1 + getal2;
            verschil = getal1 - getal2;
            product = getal1 * getal2;
            quotient = getal1 / getal2;
            goto verschil;

optelling:
            Console.Write("De som van " );
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write(getal1.ToString());
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write(" en " );
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write(getal2.ToString());
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write(" is ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine(som.ToString());
            Console.ResetColor();
            goto end;


verschil:
            Console.WriteLine("Het verschil van " + getal1.ToString() + " en " + getal2.ToString() + " is " + verschil.ToString());
goto end;

product:           
            Console.WriteLine("Het product van "  + getal1.ToString() + " en " + getal2.ToString() + " is " + product.ToString());
quotient:            
            Console.WriteLine("Het quotient van " + getal1.ToString() + " en " + getal2.ToString() + " is " + quotient.ToString());

end:
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.ResetColor();

            Console.readkey();
```

just copy paste this code and help me out of this!!

Comment: it's a bit in dutch and the "som" is a bit different because i was testing with colours.

Comment: Using `goto` all over the place has been considered very poor style since at least 1968 [Goto considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)

Comment: I was thinking for some time if this is some kind of joke - but in case you are serious: pleas don't use `goto` **ever**

Comment: After you have tested the `Console.ReadLine()` against "+", you are done with that line. The test for "-" tests a *new* line. Also: please don't use "goto", those make the code hard to read. Use mathods to split your codes in blocks and use the `if`s to decide what block to call.

Comment: Looks like a batch file

Comment: Goto is only for `serious programmers` of 10k rep and over. In the last 15 years I have used only 2 of them.

Comment: it's not like GOTO is never used, it depends on programmer, where it is best suited, if it is like it is never used, why this is available in c#?

Comment: The main use case for goto I have found is if you want to emulate switch statement fallthrough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your *fundamental* problem here is that you are naively translating a batch file into C#, rather than thinking about what the batch file does and writing a program in C# that does the same thing, using the style and conventions of C#.

The *specific* problem here is not your use of `goto`, but rather that every time you call `Console.ReadLine` it *reads another line*.  When you say:

```
    if (Console.ReadLine() == "+")
    {
        goto second;
    }
    else if (Console.ReadLine() == "-")
    {
        goto second1;
    }
```

That means "if the current line is not `+` then check to see if the **next** line is `-`".   You meant to say

```
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == "+")
    {
        goto second;
    }
    else if (line == "-")
    {
        goto second1;
    }
```

Whereas later in your program you correctly call `Console.ReadLine` to read the next line. Remember, *every* time you call `Console.ReadLine` in your program you are instructing the console to *read the next line*, not *re-read the current line*. You seem to want it to mean one thing sometimes and another thing other times.

Comment: @user2855957: You're welcome. If you believe that an answer addresses your question, please mark it as "accepted". That way other people who read this question will know that it has been answered already.